# Angular / NgRx: Handle form depends on NGRX action

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

I have an Angular app and using NgRx to perform all actions but stuck with proper perform actions for checking current user password before apply changes in currently editing user:
User edit component calling component with modal and passes data into this component. Here is all ok.

```
user-edit.component.ts excerpt

onModalOpen(type) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationModalComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.modal = true;
    switch (type) {
      case "isEdit":
        modalRef.componentInstance.modalOptions = {
          header: "Update user data",
          label: `For update ${this.currentUser.userLogin} type you password`,
        };
        break;
      case "isDelete":
        modalRef.componentInstance.modalOptions = {
          header: "Delete user",
          label: `For delete ${this.currentUser.userLogin} type your password`,
        };
        break;
    }
  }
```

Confirmation modal subscribes on store data in constructor:

```
confirmation-modal.component.ts excerpt

constructor(
    private store: Store<fromStore.AppState>,
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
  ) {
    this.confirmSub = this.store
      .select(fromStore.getUserState)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this.confirmError = data.errorMessage;
          this.currentAuthUser = data.currentUser;
          this.currentAuthUserState = data.checkUserResult;
        }
      });
    this.confirmationGroup = new FormGroup({
      currentUserPassword: new FormControl(null),
    });
  }
```

and then on it's submit method component dispatches UserCheck action from store and tries to fetch state

```
confirmation-modal.component.ts excerpt

onSubmit() {
    this.currentAuthUser = {
      ...this.currentAuthUser,
      userPassword: this.confirmationGroup.value.currentUserPassword,
    };

    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UserCheck(this.currentAuthUser));
    this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState);
  }
```

Store method works, but obtain data only if I click on submit button twice, on other hand it shows store data with async pipe after first onSubmit method call.

Please, point me a direction, how can I properly fetch store data from subscription, made in constructor or maybe redo whole component logic.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by: store method works, but obtain data only if I click on submit button twice?

Comment: I mean that State updates in confirmation component only after I click button twice. First time button click send request to store, second time it updates inside modal component.

Comment: Ok and why are you selecting data after submit and not doing anything with them? Since it's a subscription to which you are not subscribing, nothing actually happens.

Comment: It's not true. I subscribed in constructor to track this store property, as well as other necessary to component logic, and successfully obtain this property in async way. But I need to get result of request to store after I fire submit method by clicking button for first time

Answer (score 0):

Move your subscription from constructor to ngOnInit function. Constructor is not exactly the best place to do such things. Otherwise you have to deal with detection checks which can be easily omitted. And don't forget to unsubscribe when the modal is closed otherwise you might get some strange behavior and memory leaks.

```
// confirmation-modal.component.ts excerpt

class ConfirmationModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
      private store: Store<fromStore.AppState>,
      public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) {
      this.confirmationGroup = new FormGroup({
        currentUserPassword: new FormControl(null),
      });
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.confirmSub = this.store.select(fromStore.getUserState)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          this.confirmError = data.errorMessage;
          this.currentAuthUser = data.currentUser;
          this.currentAuthUserState = data.checkUserResult;
        }
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.currentAuthUser = {
      ...this.currentAuthUser,
      userPassword: this.confirmationGroup.value.currentUserPassword,
    };

    this.store.dispatch(fromStore.UserCheck(this.currentAuthUser)); 
    // new should not be necessary if you are using newest NgRx version
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.confirmStub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

This should help hopefully.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't works for my case. I've already tried to subscribe from ngOnInit, but it works same way as if I subscribe from constructor. And for sure I remember to unsubscribe with ngOnDestroy)

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?